# How to remove specific object in array with assigned specific delete button

Tags: javascript, arrays

In the below image link ,the delete button with each object in the array, i want JavaScript coding once i click the delete button with Alex it should only remove Alex data, when i click delete button with Marry it should only delete marry data. Should not work like pop and shift.

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! You're new so you might not know some norms of the community. For starters, you should share a simplified version of your code so that we may help you. If you're looking for someone to program for you given a set of requirements, it's probably best to seek a freelancer on some other site.

Comment: Please include your  code that you have tried so far

Comment: @Supercool. below is just deleting portion code having issue.                                
      var allstudents =[];
 function del(){
  
  for(var x of allstudents){
   if(allstudents.index == allstudents[x]){
    allstudents.splice(allstudents[x],1);
    display();
   }
   
  }
 }

Comment: not in the comments...include in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While calling the delete function pass a unique identifer in the list, such as id or name.Here iam considering name.So using `Array.findIndex()` you can find index of desired student.

```
let index=results.findIndex( student => student.name == name);
```

Above will return the index where student's name is same as name passed in delete function

```html
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="name">
<input type="text" id="marks" placeholder="marks">
<button onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
<div id="results">
</div>
<script>
       var results=[];
       var studentName=document.querySelector('#name');
       var studentMarks=document.querySelector('#marks');
       var resultsDiv=document.querySelector('#results')
       function submit(){
             results.push({ name:studentName.value,marks:studentMarks.value});
             render();
       }
       function render(){
           resultsDiv.innerHTML="";
           for(object of results)
            resultsDiv.innerHTML+= `Name:${object.name}  Marks :${object.marks} <button onclick="deleteStudent('${object.name}')">Delete</button><br>`;            

       }
       function deleteStudent(name){
           let index=results.findIndex( student => student.name == name);
           results.splice(index,1);
           render();
       }
</script>
```